# why does xcode try to convert googlemap cocoapods frameworks?

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, cocoapods

I am trying to create a new project with xcode 8 and google maps cocoapods. I have read that their framework is in swift 3.0, but whenever I install the framework on the project and open .xcworspace file and xcode automatically prompts be to convert to 3.0 or 2.3. The project is a newly created project that was created in swift 3.0.

I am running cocoapods 1.0.1. Thank you again for all that respond.

Contents of podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'googleMaps' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'

  target 'googleMapsTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'googleMapsUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: can you show us the contents of your podfile please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to update cocoapods to pre version `1.1.0.rc.3`

Run this command on terminal

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Then create a new project and install pod for GoogleMaps. Mine is working fine and Xcode never asks to convert to 2.3.

Running `pod --version` on termial will return this

```
Rajan-Maheshwari354:~ rajan$ pod --version
1.1.0.rc.3
```

If this didn't work, just try `pod update`

Comment: I did this, updated my repo as well: pod repo update. I think a combination of both helped. The last one allowed me to update to the latest Alamofire, which was also cauing a bunch of errors.

Comment: Does the cocoapods repo get updated with a new install or that has to be done manually all the time?

Comment: its better to run the command atleast once on every new updation of cocoapods. I remember that I didn't update the repo part, though worked fine.